# java, correct number of inputs on one line entry

Tags: java, validation, input

Forgive me if this has already been asked, but I am trying to fill an array of user defined size, but I want to make sure any extra input is either dumped or triggers an error to reprompt for input. My assignment requires that all input for an array is done on one line, with spaces separating individual values. The program works fine, and seeing how we are still in the beginning of the class I don't think that we are expected to know how to filter the quantity of inputs on a single line, but it is something that still bugs me.

I have searched for some time now for a solution, but everything thing I find is not quite what I am looking for. I thought doing a while(scannerVariable != "\n") would work, but once I thought about it more I realized that wouldn't do anything for my problem since the new line character is only being encountered once per array regardless of the number of inputs. The snippet with the problem is below:

```
public static double[] getOperand(String prompt, int size)
{
    System.out.print(prompt);
    double array[];
    array = new double[size];
    for(int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        array[count] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    return array;
}
```

All I need is some way of validating the number of inputs or dumping/ignoring extra input, so that there is no trash in the buffer to skip input that follows. The only way I can think of is counting the number of spaces and comparing that against the size of the array -1. I don't think that would be reliable though, and I'm not sure how to extract a whitespace character for the count unless I were to have all the input go into a string and parse it. I can post more code or provide more details if needed. As always, thanks for any help!

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, but I will tell you that you should be doing `input.nextDouble()` inside a `try-catch` block in case the user enters e.g. text instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you. Function that allows the entry of numbers on a line separated by spaces. Valid numbers are stored in a list of type `Double`.

```
public static void entersDouble () {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        ArrayList<Double> numbers= new ArrayList<>();            
        System.out.print("Please enter numbers: ");           
        s=input.nextLine();
        String [] strnum = s.split("\\s+");

        int j=0;
        while(j<strnum.length){
            try {
                numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(strnum[j++]));
            }       
            catch(Exception exception) {
            }
        }   
        for (Double n : numbers)
            System.out.println(n);            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that rather than trying to work out the number of inputs up front you would be better off trying to read them one by one and then taking appropriate action if it's too long or too short.

For example

```
public static double[] getOperands(String prompt, int size) {
    double[] operands = new operands[size];
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);+
        int operandCount = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            double val = scanner.nextDouble();
            if (operandCount < size) 
                operands[operandCount++] = val;
        }
        if (operandCount == size)
            return operands;
        else
            System.out.println("Enter " + size + " decimals separated by spaces.");
    }
}
```